# How to avoid mails going to SPAM (Configuring SMTP Server on IIS)

Tags: iis, smtp

How to configure SMTP Server in IIS such that the mails sent from my Server doesn't go to the spam box of gmail, yahoo, or hotmail ?

Comment: The common response to this at my workplace is "don't use SMTP Server on IIS" but that's hardly a productive answer for you ;)

Comment: Similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam

Answer (score 1):

To find out what all you can do to avoid emails going to SPAM folder, see this [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit difficult to understand. I think there's two ways to interpret your question with two very different answers. I'll try to give both meanings I see and an answer to each question below.

> *1. Is there a setting I can choose on IIS's SMTP server (or any other mail
>   server for that matter) that will stop
>   other people marking email sent from my
>   server as junk.*
>
> No... There are things you can do with
>   DNS settings to manage email
>   reputation (spf, etc) but ultimately
>   this is a choice made by the
>   *receiving* server's operator, and also by their users.
>
> *2. Help, I think my server is being exploited by spammers, because the
>   legitimate mail I'm sending is being
>   rejected with messages that indicate I
>   have an open relay or am participating
>   in sending spam. What do I do?*
>
> In general terms, you need to make
>   sure that
>
> - You are only accepting email
>     to send through this server from your
>     own internal processes...  in other
>     words that your email server is
>     configured to only accept and forward
>     email from servers you control.
> - That
>     these processes are secure - there was
>     a spate of people exploiting issues in
>     email forms on webpages, for example,
>     to get around the problem I mention
>     above.
> - And any authentication you use
>     to connect from the process you want
>     to send email via this server hasn't
>     been compromised.