# why my emails are going into spam folder

Tags: domain, subdomain, spam

I have a domain name hosted at godaddy and if I send an email from gmail to a friend with a link to my domain or a subdomain of it in the content, the email is sent to the spam folder.

I never sent batch emails. I use that domain name just for some personal tests. Why yahoo, gmail or other email services consider the emails with my personal domain as a spam email?

Comment: If you don't insert the URL with your domain, it doesn't go to the spam folder?

Comment: only if I add a link to that domain, my emails are sent to the spam folder of my friends

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you're sending email through a shared ip address at GoDaddy which has a bad reputation. This is one of the risks with shared hosting, just because you're doing everything right, it doesn't mean that everyone using the same shared resource is.

You can check the IP your email is coming from against multiple black lists at sites like [this](http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/). If your not sure of the ip, look at the headers in the email that blocked as spam in Google and look for the `Received: header with the connection from GoDaddy to Google.

It's very possible that the IP won't appear in any public RBL, but will be on internal RBLs used by Google and Yahoo.

Comment: You can also check the domain name you mentioned against the same lists.

Answer (score 1):

First something general: You can see in the source code of the email why it was tagged as spam. Most spam filters set some information in there. it will look something like this:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on server.domain.com
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-0.8 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,DC_IMAGE_SPAM_HTML,
DC_IMAGE_SPAM_TEXT,DC_PNG_UNO_LARGO,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE autolearn=no
version=3.3.1
```

With some googling you will find out what everything means.

And now regarding your question: It could be that your domain name has some string in it that is related to porn. A friend of mine had once a similar problem. The administrator within his company decided that "boys" somewhere in a domain name is not work related and potential porn. So he started to block it. The problem was now that my friend had to be in contact with "boyscouts" (in domain names often written together like this) because they were sending fund-raising requests to him.

So my recommendation is to check the email source code. Maybe your domain name is not your only problem. So if you can fix the other things then you can still send emails with your domain name in it.