# I don't have Sendmail but port 25 is still using by Sendmail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

I am running this command:

```
telnet 87.106.xxx.xxx 25
```

And it says

```
Trying 87.106.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

But `telnet localhost` is running properly.

Then I ran this command

```
sudo netstat -plntu
```

and it gave me:

```
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:25    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      9518/sendmail: MTA:
```

But the problem is I don't have Sendmail. I am using postfix.

I tried to uninstall sendmail with `apt-get purge sendmail` But it gives error:

```
Package sendmail is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am looking for a way so that the post 25 should be used by Postfix.

Comment: Try to restart postfix AND look some lines produced from maillog.

Comment: @masegaloeh Yes I restarted and maillog says that: postfix/master[11258]: terminating on signal 15
postfix/master[11591]: daemon started -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix

Comment: What happens if you try `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`?

Comment: @Massimo The same error: Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Please do a `which sendmail` to look if there's really no binary.

Comment: Looks like it's keeping the port open but it's not really accepting connections, then...

Comment: @Massimo "which sendmail" gives me-> /usr/sbin/sendmail.

Comment: Please post the output of `postconf -n`, so we can see if you have anything misconfigured. And also the output of `sudo iptables -t nat -L`, to see if anything is blocked by your server internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sendmail is still installed*, the package is called `sendmail-bin`, `sendmail-base`, `opensmtpd` etc.

```
apt-get purge sendmail-bin sendmail-base opensmtpd
```

Found using the package search on packages.ubuntu.com: [Content search for sendmail](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sendmail&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)

*) Your `which sendmail` gave as output `/usr/sbin/sendmail`. `which` returns the path of an executable, which would be executed if typed on the command line. This means, the sendmail binary was still existing.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I run this command and send mail is not removed. But I when I run {which sendmail} I still can see {/usr/sbin/sendmail}

Comment: Very interesting, let's see what's the output of this one: `dpkg -l | grep -E 'dovecot|opensmtpd'`
It displays only installed packages.

Comment: @Kami, looks like in this case, that binary is sendmail binary [from postfix](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html). See http://serverfault.com/questions/244263/is-postfix-the-same-thing-as-sendmail

Comment: @masegaloeh Oh, I overlooked that! So, that's probably not the solution.

Comment: @masegaloeh :( I have uninstalled using the commands provided by sebix. Now what I have to do. By the way my Postfix is now running properly and sending emails as desired. And Telnet command is also running...

Comment: @Kami Congratulation, you have nothing to do :)). Before you do sebix solution, the sendmail binary is independent program from postfix. After you uninstall it, postfix install its own implementation of sendmail binary for compatibility reason. See the two links given in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

```
apt-get purge sendmail*
```

This will remove all its files and configurations.

Step 2:

```
kill 9518 # or 
killall sendmail
```

This should kill the sendmail process that's using your port.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your `postfix` is just listening it on `localhost`, so all you gotta do is change `inet_interfaces` from `localhost` to `all`.

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# grep ^inet_interfaces /etc/postfix/main.cf 
inet_interfaces = all
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]#
```

don't forget to restart `postfix` after that.

*** UPDATE ***

It looks like you have you're running `sendmail` and not postfix, so you probably have something like this inside of your `sendmail.mc` file:

```
# grep -E '^DAEMON_OPTIONS.*Addr' /etc/mail/sendmail.mc 
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
#
```

you need to remove `Addr` part, rebuild your `sendmail.cf` and restart `sendmail`.

Comment: Yes inet_interfaces is set to all already. "inet_interfaces = all". I checked that I cannot access it with any port. e.g. telnet 87.106.xxx.xxx 33, gave me same error. I checked different number of ports but its still give me the same error.

Comment: if it's already set to `all` from `localhost` than I'm guessing you didn't restart your postfix yet, as that's the only configuration change is needed in order to start listening on all interfaces.

Comment: I even started my system but still its the same.

Comment: @Kami, I just updated my answer with `sendmail` as well, as it seems like you're running `sendmail` and not `postfix`.

Comment: Yes This file exist in my system. How Can I remove sendmail. Because apt-get purge sendmail says that "Package sendmail is not installed, so not removed". I don' want to use this stupid Sendmail :(