# Will ISPs accept mail from a postfix null client with no dns record

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, email

I am concerned my mail server setup may cause some ISPs to reject mail that is sent by it.

I am using Postfix to send mail for a web application, light load, user notices. It also sends cron notices and "monit" alerts. It is for sending mail only. I guess it wants to be "null client".

The postfix server and webapp live on the same box. The webapp builds the "to" and "from" email mail headers.

Server: 123.foobar.com
Website Domain: mysupersite.com

Mail that is getting sent by postfix has:
from: foo@mysupersite.com
HELO: 123.foobar.com (123.123.123.123)
(I am not sure this is enough header information to describe my condition)

I have read that some mail servers will reject incoming mail where the "from" email address domain does not match the sending servers domain...

To throw a twist into the mix, this server does not have a dns record.  I have  read that some servers are configured this way on purpose.

For example:
"dig 123.foobar.com +short" & "dig -x 123.123.123.123 +short" give no answer for my server domain.

So there seems to be no way for a mail server to see if HELO is telling the truth. IF the accepting mail server is even checking.

As of now, mail is getting sent as I describe and it arrives to its destination but only a small amount of test mails.

But is this the right way? Is there a better way? Should I send my mail through a relay host? I have more questions than answers. Please help!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/48428/984

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this type of email (server) will relay through a properly running SMTP server to reduce the chances of the emails getting filtered - something like your ISP's relay will usually work well enough.

Comment: Looking more at my resources using a relay is not a good option right now. The example domain above, 123.foobar.com, has been given a dns record. So the mail server box can be resolved. Hopefully that will less the chance of getting filterd.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need to have matching server and email addresses. But:

If you want to send mails as `someone@example.com` and use a sending host named `amailer.smtprelay.invalid` there is nothing uncommon with that. This is how Millions of mails get send every day. Just look at Google Apps Mail, where the sending host is something ending with `google.com` whereas the hosted domain could be `example.net`.

The only requirements that you have to follow are that you have consistent DNS entries for `example.com` and `amailer.smtprelay.invalid`. That means that you have either a MX record or at least an A record for `example.com` (doesn't matter where they point to, but must be valid). And on top of that you need consistency in the DNS for `amailer.smtprelay.invalid` so that this name points to `0.1.2.3` and `0.1.2.3` has an PTR record to `amailer.smtprelay.invalid`. And the HELO/EHLO string of the server must also match with the name `amailer.smtprelay.invalid`.

There is one exception to that. If your sending server is not something like `amailer.smtprelay.invalid` but `3-2-1-0.dynamic.isp.invalid` then you are lost as this is mostly an indication that your host is in a dynamic IP range so that many SMTP servers will refuse to accept your mails. Direct sending from dynamic IPs is not prohibited but not recommended.