# every email marked as SPAM or not even delivered?

Tags: email, email-server, spam

I am having a very serious problem!

I registered the domain http://codepigeon.com a while back (2 months) and have dev. an app to easily make changes to ones source code across multiple webpages or websites.

But the app is not yet public. So there have been close to 0 emails sent!

But each time I sent an email it is marked as SPAM or does not even get delivered!

I tried no-reply@codepigeon.com, register@codepigeon.com .... I tried sending then email through CPANEL through Mail and php

The server is not blocked http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a108.163.232.130

It is marked as SPAM by google

this is a dedi server
(same thing with all other accounts)

I do not understad why this is happening!!!

Thanks

Comment: It is marked as spam by who or what? You forgot to tell us what this problem is about.

Comment: by google and most other mail apps

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS is broken. `108.163.232.130` reverses to `s1.om-p.com` which doesn't resolve.

Comment: but thats the server? how can I fix this

Comment: Get your upstream provider to allocate the PTR record for your IP address to a real domain (maybe even yours?)