# Major web hoster detects my emais as SPAM or JUNK, why

Tags: spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Whenever I send emails from my domain using PHP it goes to spam , 
when ever user register to my site I send them message saying welcome along with a image and Facebook Url,

No I Not spamming.
No my IP is not blocked by any spam guard service.

What I need to do so that whenever I send email it goes to inbox and not in spam or junk.

PS. When I send email without any URL it goes to inbox.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using a valid (with valid I mean theoretically reachable, valid domain etc.) from-address. If not, this should be the very very first thing to do.

You should have a proper [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) for your domain like:

```
example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx -all"
- or -
example.com. IN SPF "v=spf1 a mx -all"
```

Third: It is always good to write some "normal" text in your email. Most scanners determine a ratio between links and text. If it is to high your mail could be spam. Additionally it is always a good idea to provide the user with some help and info. :-)

If this does not help look at the headers of your "marked as spam" mail. Sometimes you can find some kind of "score" showing the spam-probability the scanner calculated. With this value you can try out what is wrong with your mail.

Comment: I have already created SPF record... but still not working. i have few lines of text and 1 url that's all. Still they are going into junk inm gmail, yahoo, live almost in all mail hosters :(

Answer (score 2):

You should visit the "major webhoster" that's marking your mail as junk.  They all have bulk sender/postmaster help and guidelines to help you get legit email through.

Of course, telling your users to check their junk/spam folders for the registration email is another thing you should be doing.  Everyone else does this, no reason you shouldn't tell your users to expect an email within [x time] and to make sure it's not in the junk folder if it's not in the inbox by that time.

Finally, maybe you should check out our [canonical spam thread](https://serverfault.com/q/419407/118258) - if you have a better idea of what people do to fight spam, it should help you make your registration emails look less like spam.