# Mails marked as SPAM on some machine but not on all on outlook 2010

Tags: wordpress, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

iam using wordpress and contact form 7 plugin with wp-mail-smtp . When i send mails through my application on some machines on outlook 2010 the mails go to JUNK folder while on some machines on outlook 2010 the mails come to INBOX.

Iam unable to find the problem any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to add the sender of those messages to your safe senders list. That way emails from that address will never end up in the junk folder.

Beyond that, Microsoft purposely keeps Outlook's junk classification methods undocumented. No one knows what they are exactly. Therefore, it is impossible to tell you what to do to avoid the junk folder.