# Was around Postfix and PHP sent emails always get tagged as spam

Tags: php, email, debian, postfix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

I have a legitimate website that sends out emails using postfix for user signup validation. I am running a VPS with Debian on Linode.

Is there a way to somehow validate my server, so that other servers know I am not sending spam?  I don't always want them ending up in the spam folder, especially on gmail.

Comment: could be many reasons.. badly configured vps (helo/rdns/a-record), bad/missing mail headers from your php script, blacklisted somewhere.. you might want to post more details to get better help (the headers of such a message after is has been received by gmail for example)

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues that need to be taken in consideration while sending an email. I have seen that the most common is missing of DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail).

To investigate your problem I would suggest you to send an email to check@isnotspam.com . use an email address that you can receive the emails back. check@isnotspam.com will send back an debugging email where you can identify the problems that lead your emails to be marked as spam.