# Hotmail blocks company emails, when hyperlink is inserted in the message body

Tags: spam, email

I received the following results:

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         neutral
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

Mail sent from my company email to Hotmail recipients goes to "junk" if message body contains link to my company web, examples:

1. `http://www.mycompanydomain.com`
2. `www.mycompanydomain.com`

but `mycompanydomain.com` is OK and delivered to inbox well!

I think Hotmail filters/blacklists my full domain name as a keyword and therefore this issue has nothing to do with rest antiSPAM stuff checks, like SPF, DomainKeys, DKIM, Sender-ID, SpamAssassin - all these checks are OK and set well!

Answer (score 7):

You're messages are probably considered borderline spam without the links, and the addition of links pushes them over the threshold.

Hotmail uses a variety of heuristics to determine if a message is spam. The main ones are:

- SPF - Do you have a SPF record ***properly*** configured for your domain?
- DKIM - Do you have DKIM ***properly*** configured for your domain and outgoing mail is signed?
- SenderScore.org - Check your IP(s) (note that this works on a feedback loop, the more e-mail addresses you send to, where the majority of your messages are considered ham, the better your score; if you conduct testing, use only one destination testing address to minimize the effect on your score; similarly try not to send spam to a ton of addresses or your reputation will be trashed).
- Common content scoring (similar to SpamAssassin if you know how it works) - If you're sending marketing, automated, or similar e-mails on a regular basis, run your messages through SpamAssassin and see what it thinks. Hotmail doesn't use SA to my knowledge, but most systems work similarly enough that you'll get a good idea of where you stand.

SPF, DKIM, and SpamAssassin can all be [checked quickly be sending a test message to a verifier](http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/).

This Canonical Question answer the more generic question of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Some of the information in this one may be useful, as it speaks to the other side of the coin: [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)

Comment: Mail sent from my company email to hotmail recipients goes to "junk" if message body contains link to my company web, examples:

1) "http://www.mycompanydomain.com" 2) "www.mycompanydomain.com"

but "mycompanydomain.com" is ok and delivered to inbox well!

I think Hotmail filters/blacklists my full domain name as a keyword and therefore this issue has nothing to do with rest antiSPAM stuff checks, like SPF, DomainKeys, DKIM, Sender-ID, SpamAssassin - all these checks are ok and set well!

Please advise!

Comment: DKIM did not pass. SA returned Ham, but what are the details of that result??

Comment: "SA ham" doesn't mean that it is not passed or "bad", as well as DKIM result "neutral"