# SPF, DKIM, PTR & friends Passed, but postfix mail goes into spam How to Fix it?

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam

I recently setup an email server with static IP address, (Ubuntu 12.04 & Postfix); Everyting looks OK, I did te **test@allaboutspam.com** test and everything passes in green (except for BATV format wich it's yellow, but as far as I know it is optional). The **[Brandon Checketts](http://www.brandonchecketts.com/emailtest.php)** email test passes OK too, the message it's not marked as spam in the tests, the IP is not blacklisted, but when I send something to a **gmail.com** or **outlook.com** address it goes into spam, How to fix it?

Here you have my email headers:

```
Delivered-To: saul.xenode@gmail.com
Received: by 10.49.49.106 with SMTP id t10csp21371qen;
Thu, 9 May 2013 07:56:47 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.60.101.163 with SMTP id fh3mr4561699oeb.95.1368111406659;
Thu, 09 May 2013 07:56:46 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <uranosrv@2travel.info>
Received: from 2travel.info (2travel.info. [187.163.74.217])
by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m9si2088545obv.129.2013.05.09.07.56.46
for <saul.xenode@gmail.com>
(version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
Thu, 09 May 2013 07:56:46 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of uranosrv@2travel.info designates 187.163.74.217 as permitted sender) client-ip=187.163.74.217;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=pass (google.com: domain of uranosrv@2travel.info designates 187.163.74.217 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=uranosrv@2travel.info;
dkim=pass (test mode) header.i=@2travel.info
Received: by 2travel.info (Postfix, from userid 1000)
id 84FC440BFF; Thu, 9 May 2013 09:57:00 -0500 (CDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=2travel.info;
s=2travelkey; t=1368111420;
bh=LXnlcM8uGSNLjh0KpvoP9Tb5EqbHG59Qc5759/vsCFo=;
h=Subject:To:Date:From;
b=tt3nk9ZG3/R6xp4plcWVpyB7AdlFqXrbqMSHb69BSanMHTgNM49oi3ljHx99z7Olq
895wFMX6QL4o2eAJBPf5fib+IaSVeRzJz0ScC3gIjE52xATc6CzPPfkWYT+oIWQJZ7
9/UI4JcwTxaAf33XYi6pCn8OgSRGz4ut12hElL5w=
Subject: test
To: <saul.xenode@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.2)
Message-Id: <20130509145700.84FC440BFF@2travel.info>
Date: Thu, 9 May 2013 09:57:00 -0500 (CDT)
From: uranosrv@2travel.info (Urano Server)
prueba
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try sending more realistic content than 'test'. Message contents count a lot.

Comment: My 'test' messages usually went through, it is hard to understand why it ends up in spam without some indication of what it fails at.. unless maybe your email or domain has been signaled as spam by end users (or something very similar has).

Comment: This is really something you need to ask the destination domains about -- we're not responsible for mail policy on the internet. [It sounds like you're doing most of what you should be](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam), so now you have to talk to the admins at the destination domain to find out why they don't like your mail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup rdns for your IP address, otherwise gmail, outlook will mark your mail as spam.

Check your Ip email reputation also in senderbase [IP reputaion](http://www.senderbase.org/help/blocked) It should good or neutral.

Comment: It's neutral, and yes, rDNS it's available for my domain, IP resolves to "domain.tld" and domain resolves to IP also, any other ideas?

Comment: If you click your Spam label and open one of the messages, you'll see a message at the top with a brief explanation about why that particular message was placed in Spam. or follow below link ofr more detail        https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en&ctx=mail

Answer (score 0):

Email deliverability is a whole industry onto itself. When you start working with a company that helps you with these issues one of the first things they have you do is set yourself up with FBLs for all the major email providers. (Google doesn't participate in that one.) This can significantly improve your inbox percentage (assuming you act on the messages.) Speaking of, do you have a good bounce processing setup?