# How to Prevent email going to Spam

Tags: domain-name-system, ubuntu-12.04, web-hosting, ptr-record

I have changed web hosting from hostgator to servermania. I setup my email using ISPConfig 3 control panel. Now, my email was flag as spam by gmail.

When I test my email using test@allaboutspam.com, allaboutspam.com replied the following:

> > Reverse DNS: <> = Reverse DNS does not exist for Email server. Ask your ISP to set reverse DNS for Email server IP to match your Mail server Host name (in FQDN format).
> >
> > Email server is not using BATV format while sending out emails. BATV is recommended to ensure that your users do not become a victim of bounce floods.
> >
> > does not have any SPF records set. Using SPF minimizes the chances of your Email being rejected or be classified as SPAM. Ideally, the SPF records for  must return 'pass' for your Email server IP <111.111.111.111>. For more details on publishing SPF records for your domain, please refer to http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html
> >
> > Email does not contain any DKIM/Domain Keys Signature and the published Domain Keys policy does not specify whether to accept or reject unsigned Emails. Signing your Outbound emails and clearly specifying a policy to accept signed emails will minimize chances of your Email being considered as SPAM.

I have five IP Address given by servermania and I told them to add a PTR to my two IP address which holds two nameserver named ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com. I don't know if it just the nameserver that needs the PTR for reverse DNS or I need the five (5) IP addresses to have a PTR record from my ISP (servermania.) or I need all domain/website that I host to have a PTR record.

Help please.

P.S. I'm using postfix and dovecot as my mail server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read carefully: it says "Reverse DNS does not exist for *Email server* ." but you added PTRs to your *nameserver* IPs. Instead, add the correct PTR for the IP that is actually sending the mails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already emailed servermania to add the PTR record on the IP Address that is used when I send email. How about SPF? How to setup it? I don't know what to under the "Text" field. There are 3 field to input a Text record, Hostname, Text, and TTL.

Comment: I generally do not recommend adding SPF records unless you are a) planning to send bulk mail to gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc and b) know *exactly* what you are doing.

Comment: No. I will not send bulk mail. So a PTR Record is enough? No need to worry about sfp?

Comment: assuming your PTR has a matching A record and your mailserver presents a plausible non-generic HELO (again matching PTR/A record in the best case) you're *usually* good to go.