# Send thousands emails for newsletters

Tags: email, ip, blacklist-prevention, newsletters

i have a huge list (5K emails) of email addresses, it's not spam , these are newsletter emails i have to send.

I'm wondering , since i have to send these emails with my personal account (verified) which is the best practice to not get banned or to not put my website banned or blacklisted in anyway?

i have to link to my website inside those emails cause i have to include a link to a new feature on the website.

I was planning to send email using a php script, configuring php on my personal gmail SMTP params etc,  but they are a lot of emails, about 5K/6K

Any help appriciated thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to use your "personal account"? And why would you try to send them through Gmail?

Comment: @MichaelHampton cause each newsletter subscriber knows my email and i have to send them trough that, also for resulting clear to them, it's not spam, i'm sending using my real account

Comment: Gmail will cut you off pretty much instantly if you try this. You really should use a third party service.

Comment: @MichaelHampton which one sorry? and also what will happen to my website? :( cause i have to link to my website inside the email body :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Answer (score 1):

If you try this through a personal gmail account it will probably get banned.  Your website might even get on some blacklists.

The best way to handle this is to use a reputable third party mailing list service.  [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) is one such service I know of (not a recommendation just an example).  Another is [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com). They will handle dealing with blacklist services and ensure there are proper unsubscribe methods in each email.

These services will cost you money.  A quick look at their plans says somewhere between $50-100 per month.  That's a lot less than what your time will cost dealing with ensuring unsubscribing works, getting off blacklists, etc.  Doing it yourself is quite difficult.  You will spend most of your time begging to get off blacklists.  Doing it from a personal email account would be nearly impossible.

You can set what address the email appears to cone from at most services so your subscribers will still see the email as coming from you and can reply normally.

Comment: My privacy policy doesn't allows to share email addresses with others

Comment: Your plan shares then with gmail just as much as you would share with a mailing list service