# Steps to make sure network is not blacklisted...Again

Tags: security, email, exchange-2010, email-server, blacklist

I have an interesting issue.  I have a client that just got blacklisted due to spam being sent out over the last 2 days.  I have my firewall configured to only allow mail to go outbound on port 25 from our mail server (Exchange 2010) exclusively and I have verified that there are no open relay's on our transport rules.  We are running Vipre Business and after running deep scans with updated definitions all computers come back clean.  I ran a message tracking report on our Exchange server that shows all mail sent via the mail server over the last couple of weeks and didn't see anything malicious or out of the ordinary.  I have also verified that there are no home devices or rouge computers on the network.  For all practical purposes it appears that the network is clean, but we still wound up on 5 or 6 blacklists...Where should I start looking next? Is there a "best practices" guide that can help eradicate this issue?

Thanks in advance!
msindle

Comment: What type of internet connection is this network hung off of?

Comment: Its a cable connection with a static IP from our local ISP, did that answer your question?

Comment: Do any of those blacklists give any specific information about why they listed you?

Comment: Thanks for the responses and I hope everyone had a good weekend.  @Gordon Unfortunately they just said please check your logs.  One of my coworkers went ahead and delisted them, which i'm not entirely comfortable with, and wished they hadn't because now I cant see the reason for blacklisting.  There was nothing that stood out to me in our logs, just normal mailings...any thoughts?

Comment: For "best practices" see - http://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance your messages are queueing up and then going out in bursts?  We had that problem with some of our production servers; when a huge queue of emails goes out at once, some of the spam filters will detect that as problematic behavior.

I assume you're using [Spamhaus](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) to check their listings:  we found ourselves on their lists whenever there was an issue, and they're easy to have your listing removed.

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam) previous serverfault topic should help you on the way towards best practices.  Also, 
look [here](http://wiki.junkemailfilter.com/index.php/Keeping_Your_Server_Off_Black_Lists) for more tips.  Best of luck!