# Assistance on why email is being marked as spam

Tags: email, spam, spam-filter

We are trying to send out a mass email for a client of ours through a third party sender and it is always being sent to the spam folder rather than the inbox. I have below the headers from the email.

Do you have any thoughts on why it might be being filtered as spam? Or how we might be able to fix it?

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRyU+pBy2R9QCr01wX+2TQb16V+IWYKH89OEXx2kXRCi0YCCbAc2czEzqYF2bH27mAPgHi3rzu7bpgBsHbtZAyLKnNk8fJmBxyu+VguRUNe13q5zZaaanxKw=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=softfail (sender IP is 64.250.95.18) smtp.mailfrom=almirall@cgdmcanada.com; dkim=none header.d=cgdmcanada.com; x-hmca=fail header.id=almirall@cgdmcanada.com
X-SID-PRA: almirall@cgdmcanada.com
X-AUTH-Result: FAIL
X-SID-Result: FAIL
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD00
X-Message-Info: 11chDOWqoTky60iQsYaQEbDMsbZfaHn4uXeEdYJ+hJPs/IZZs8+jCAsGYVfWXZjOH0CIVQtMZgN6eci97N8hFZVMIRvFnbKffwelTwXTo1W1G4O4NpDJy0u1RYUR3/Eg8I879+IgZwjq8NUi6hFsCbgaJ4tlHCzI9/qIYnxslvFwe5kU9IzpYCxXwgvPEsGAo4ciKuRN7XjS74cqqwszN1kev1/vz0rc
Received: from mx01.dmtel.ca ([64.250.95.18]) by SNT0-MC1-F52.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
        Thu, 14 Nov 2013 09:10:27 -0800
Received: from E1_NT (199.115.92-98.ip.mltn.standardbroadband.ca [199.115.92.98])
        by mx01.dmtel.ca (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id rAEHAQiA009774
        for <EMAIL ADDRESS REMOVED>; Thu, 14 Nov 2013 12:10:26 -0500
Message-Id: <201311141710.rAEHAQiA009774@mx01.dmtel.ca>
From: "Almirall Ltd." <almirall@cgdmcanada.com>
Subject: Introducing NEW Tudorza Genuair
To: EMAIL ADDRESS REMOVED
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="wBS=_qJqKiL3XVShQgrlM1RROrtguDYnsT"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 14 Nov 2013 12:11:04 -0500
Return-Path: almirall@cgdmcanada.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 14 Nov 2013 17:10:27.0926 (UTC) FILETIME=[6A6F8F60:01CEE15C]

This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--wBS=_qJqKiL3XVShQgrlM1RROrtguDYnsT
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="RxbxbbDQL=_vGDBlBk67MreVItV2mLXC41"

--RxbxbbDQL=_vGDBlBk67MreVItV2mLXC41
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

Introducing NEW Tudorza Genuair

--RxbxbbDQL=_vGDBlBk67MreVItV2mLXC41
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>New Page 1</TITLE>
<META http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dwindow=
s-1252">
<META content=3DFrontPage.Editor.Document name=3DProgId></HEAD>
<BODY>
<P><IMG height=3D336 src=3D"cid:015522113@14112013-2880" width=3D1021 =
border=3D0><BR><IMG height=3D673 src=3D"cid:015522113@14112013-2887" w=
idth=3D1021 border=3D0><BR><MAP name=3DFPMap0><AREA shape=3DRECT coord=
s=3D459,27,799,51 href=3D"http://webprod5.hc-sc.gc.ca/dpd-bdpp/index-e=
ng.jsp"></MAP><IMG height=3D316 src=3D"cid:015522113@14112013-288E" wi=
dth=3D1021 useMap=3D#FPMap0 border=3D0></P>
<P align=3Dcenter>This email was sent to&nbsp;you by Almirall Ltd.<BR>=
For&nbsp;removal please reply to this email with Unsubscribe in Subjec=
t Line.</P><IMG height=3D1 alt=3D"" src=3D"LINK REMOVED" width=3D1 bor=
der=3D0> </BODY></HTML>

--RxbxbbDQL=_vGDBlBk67MreVItV2mLXC41--

--wBS=_qJqKiL3XVShQgrlM1RROrtguDYnsT
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
        name="syn6692-1.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
        filename="syn6692-1.jpg"
Content-ID: <015522113@14112013-2880>
```

Comment: it would be nice to see the bounce message instead. And to name the mass mailing provider and their server addresses. There are lots of different antispam techniques, you might be hitting any one of them

Comment: Canonical answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam?rq=1

Comment: You have to recognize that sending a mass email with spam-like capitalization in the subject line "NEW", marketing a medical product (CNET claims drugs and medicines comprise ~ 30% of all spam), sent from a server without the relevant SPF records might be taken the wrong way by spam filters.  Presumably you're paying the third-party to carry out this mail campaign and if they're a professional mailing outfit then they should be well aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=softfail (sender IP is 64.250.95.18) smtp.mailfrom=almirall@cgdmcanada.com; dkim=none header.d=cgdmcanada.com; x-hmca=fail header.id=almirall@cgdmcanada.com
```

The server you're sending from (64.250.95.18) is not in your SPF record as a valid sender. Update your SPF record.

Comment: Thanks i will pass this along to who is sending out the emails for us.

Comment: I'd **fire** who is sending out the emails for you, if that's their job.

Comment: You should have control of the relevant SPF record not the third party sender.