# Configure Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for Sending Emails for/from Multiple Domains

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, ubuntu-12.04

I have a cloudserver running on rackspace with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

The server is a LAMP stack that runs multiple live websites. Most sites are wordpress while others are PHP with a few scripts that use the mail() function to send emails.

I have followed several tutorials to no avail to get emails to send. The closest I have come are somewhat successful outcomes with very significant drawbacks:

1) In one setup, I have been able to get the server to send emails, but they end up in the spam folder

2) In another, I have been able to get emails successfully into the inboxes of recipients, using an SMTP relay (through GMail), but all emails are listed as sent from the gmail address I am relaying. (I used this tutorial to achieve this: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/ )

My server has postfix installed, and is currently setup using method 2, described above.

What I would truly like, if possible, is to setup my server, using postfix or otherwise, to be able to send emails from something like noreply@domain.com, for all of the domains I currently host, as well as other domains I will surely be hosting in the future.

Ideally, new sites/domains will be added to the server, and I wont have to worry about configuring ubuntu/postfix to send emails for that domain. For instance, with the Windows server we are migrating from, we were able to add new sites/domains and send emails from those domains without any additional configuration for emails.

A lot of tutorials get into setting up PRL records and what-not to bypass spam filters - but with our windows setup, we never had to do such things. Is there a possible way to setup my ubuntu server to send emails for various domains (ie: wordpress installs on our windows server automatically send emails as wordpress@domain.com - and get by spam filters, without needing to add PRL records to the DNS Zone files)

I have been through several tutorials but the best success I have had are only those listed as 1 & 2 above.

Thank's so much for your help, I'm available to get additional info if needed, please request as needed.

Comment: downvote for publicly mentioning the super secret PRL record (and believing that windows doesn't require valid DNS records to send mail)

Comment: and also: http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam

Answer (score 0):

like this

Mantis Email SMTP setting

```
    $g_from_email                   = 'sync@you_domain.com';

    /**
     * the sender name, part of 'From: ' header in emails
     * @global string $g_from_name
     */
    $g_from_name                    = 'Mantis Bug Tracker';

    /**
     * the return address for bounced mail
     * @global string $g_return_path_email
     */
    $g_return_path_email    = 'sync@gmail.com';
```

you can change you wordpress settings