# GMail sends basic email to spam folder. SPF DKIM ok?

Tags: gmail, spam-filter, spam

I am trying to send an email from my server using Mailgun. It's a very basic plain text email but for some reason it is ending up in spam. SPF and DKIM passes. Any ideas? I don't have any clue. This is going to be for transactional email.. not spam/newsletter etc.

```
Delivered-To: tuni@gmail.com
Received: by 10.58.225.4 with SMTP id rg4csp58875vec;
        Sat, 10 May 2014 15:44:47 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.224.47.8 with SMTP id l8mr26321392qaf.24.1399761887649;
        Sat, 10 May 2014 15:44:47 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bounce+42008d.8253-tuni=gmail.com@solopaquetes.com>
Received: from mail-s80.mailgun.info (mail-s80.mailgun.info. [184.173.153.208])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t1si4017774qga.22.2014.05.10.15.44.47
        for <tuni@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 10 May 2014 15:44:47 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounce+42008d.8253-tuni=gmail.com@solopaquetes.com designates 184.173.153.208 as permitted sender) client-ip=184.173.153.208;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce+42008d.8253-tuni=gmail.com@solopaquetes.com designates 184.173.153.208 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounce+42008d.8253-tuni=gmail.com@solopaquetes.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@solopaquetes.com
DKIM-Signature: a=rsa-sha256; v=1; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mailgun.org; q=dns/txt; s=mg;
 t=1399761887; h=X-Feedback-Id: Mime-Version: Content-Type: Subject:
 From: To: Message-Id: Content-Transfer-Encoding: Date: Sender;
 bh=OohMviSghY461RHtI6dnZMKN5dgtrUlafvjOdU/u9b4=; b=McZe9/3YVh3zCw8A9qGwDNeCpRJFXRmkA/iJuXSuczZ8BPmxXLV2ThOV9VoYjapAV+5P+CM6
 PHtay3k8FtiG83Fsb6xVttRy3qb6JGWqFGGedj3m9DW2vCkF2OJzxwbaVxZLqC3V4yBAbiH5
 7h5utVhu0iKACxCwkdJ90ZGbOK8=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; d=mailgun.org; s=mg; q=dns;
 h=X-Feedback-Id: Mime-Version: Content-Type: Subject: From: To:
 Message-Id: Content-Transfer-Encoding: Date: Sender;
 b=GkRBlyzsmYFxIls71vtIRC3/bbjBTX8lsFszV8kYzI/WPoJ/mV4dFFW4wS/5jQJvrPcn7G
 n70QGPrKzRCXxrI9XLYR0YMRfHAl+1rvpF1iEy94dJs3eQnplzYW0VEweichjuveYFvQm0n5
 q9qVRkkICdC1ZdupGlCuHxKM+O1oc=
X-Feedback-Id: 527d6aa65a76180fdb8d8257:mailgun
DKIM-Signature: a=rsa-sha256; v=1; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=solopaquetes.com; q=dns/txt;
 s=pic; t=1399761887; h=Mime-Version: Content-Type: Subject: From: To:
 Message-Id: Content-Transfer-Encoding: Date: Sender;
 bh=OohMviSghY461RHtI6dnZMKN5dgtrUlafvjOdU/u9b4=; b=b09s/fYjLS2UDqaPqESsdNWYkfy/tSn0d7hdgxzxeErRgwUAiilEPjMxnrmIq71XFUAkXDkw
 1HpJryzeIywel69AfjCy4b6LjmrN/P/4gn2tD7MmdE4MPC+t84C7Vxi930Ps7A8lMbD4B3nt
 ii8997VnEGUlV+h6028f9eDX6BY=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; d=solopaquetes.com; s=pic;
 q=dns; h=Mime-Version: Content-Type: Subject: From: To: Message-Id:
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: Date: Sender;
 b=Szpfx57WdEy5XOUERaOhm7GBDTj3grOTay209h1bl8C5Y81bC3hsLxgthR7iIO7wjh5zNh
 /ywVgPcqeDzJqGFx5vKylOcEIDIbsgybdBjQNMF1E5BOgDN6jwA3oadRgMrF6YxiTpUMoSfE
 kk5dIl++NG/Y/ItJ+388om1UTkcWs=
Received: by luna.mailgun.net with HTTP; Sat, 10 May 2014 22:44:45 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ascii"
Subject: Bienvenido a Solopaquetes.com, activa tu cuenta!
From: SoloPaquetes.com <fer@solopaquetes.com>
To: tuni@gmail.com
Message-Id: <20140510224445.20658.66762@solopaquetes.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Mailgun-Sid: WyIzNGNjMiIsICJ0dW5pbG9wZXpAZ21haWwuY29tIiwgIjgyNTMiXQ==
Date: Sat, 10 May 2014 22:44:47 +0000
Sender: fer@solopaquetes.com

Testing some Mailgun awesomness!
```

Any clues will help. I don't have much experience with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/563046/emails-going-to-gmails-spam-dkim-and-spf-are-both-set-up-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While DKIM and SPF are useful in identifying yourself as a sender for that domain, spammers can use them too, so they don't guarantee delivery.

Different destinations weight different aspects of the email message differently, but here are the major points, ranked roughly from most important to least:

- **Content of the email.** Gmail appears to rely on this more than others.
- Delivery attempt rate (especially as comparison to the moving average from the IP)
- Reputation of the sending server/IP
- DNS mechanics (SPF, DKIM, PTR Records, A records, MX records, etc.)
- Reputation of the sending domain
- Message formatting, including header abnormalities

The first thing I'd do is test with the *real* content of the email you intend to send out, not "this is a test." And if it doesn't work, complain to whomever is sending your mail out (mailgun in this instance).

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for your answer. I have actually tested with the real content and was being delivered most of the time to the spam folder. That's why I started testing with very basic, non-html emails to see if the problem was the content or something else. But any content ends up in the spam folder so it must be something else. Do you know how to check if the PTR record is set up correctly looking at that email?