# Mail server and postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server

On my work we use soft what monitor how much time you was on work and send email to each employee at midnight. But we have ~300 employers, and use public mailservers like gmail. So computer there soft installed trying send ~300 emails every day, but mail server think that we send spam and don't let us send more then ~50 emails.

I looked for info and found that we can use computer with linux, install postfix on it, had actual domain name, and send ours emails to people without public mail server limitation.

So i wanted specify if it's really true or i understand this wrong. Do we need anything else for just send mail?

P.S. I'm really sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You might want to check the email and spam section of our collection of [canonical answers](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/) and for instance [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/questions/772045/)

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly set up a computer with postfix (or any number of other mail servers, for that matter) to send mail.  But that is no guarantee that you will not be grey/blacklisted if you are flagged as engaging in behaviour deemed suspicious.  There are many ways to minimise this risk, however, in terms of configuring your postfix (or whatever you choose) server correctly.  For instance, ensuring that the public IP of your mail server has an accurate DNS entry (forward and reverse) that corresponds to its true FQDN.

However, this may not actually be necessary... if you are sending these e-mails through gmail, is it possibly just that google is rate-limiting you?  If so, have you tried contacting their support to see if they will remove the limit/throttle on your account?