# postfix not sending emails

Tags: debian, postfix, exim

The log seems to show that emails are being sent, it looks like it's finding the servers to deliver mail to - but they are not getting there.

I started with exim4, but my other server had postfix, so I tried that, the results are similar. In exim, the emails were frozen. Basically not returned undeliverable, but not delivered.

Here is the log when I tried to send 3 emails with a php script - one to a hotmail account, one to gmail account, and another to a company account that's hosted on gmail.

```
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/pickup[28232]: 9B4C79DEDB: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/cleanup[28272]: 9B4C79DEDB: message-id=<20160802215901.9B4C79DEDB@myawesomedomain.com>
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/qmgr[27728]: 9B4C79DEDB: from=<www-data@myawesomedomain.com>, size=380, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/pickup[28232]: 9E9849DEE7: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/cleanup[28272]: 9E9849DEE7: message-id=<20160802215901.9E9849DEE7@myawesomedomain.com>
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/qmgr[27728]: 9E9849DEE7: from=<www-data@myawesomedomain.com>, size=378, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/pickup[28232]: A1E649DEE8: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/cleanup[28272]: A1E649DEE8: message-id=<20160802215901.A1E649DEE8@myawesomedomain.com>
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/qmgr[27728]: A1E649DEE8: from=<www-data@myawesomedomain.com>, size=383, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/smtp[28278]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug  2 21:59:01 myawesomedomain postfix/smtp[28282]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c00::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug  2 21:59:02 myawesomedomain postfix/smtp[28278]: 9E9849DEE7: to=<myexcellentemail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.232.27]:25, delay=0.57, delays=0.01/0.01/0.29/0.27, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1470175142 u184si197895qkh.319 - gsmtp)
Aug  2 21:59:02 myawesomedomain postfix/qmgr[27728]: 9E9849DEE7: removed
Aug  2 21:59:02 myawesomedomain postfix/smtp[28277]: 9B4C79DEDB: to=<myexcellentemail@hotmail.com>, relay=mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104]:25, delay=0.65, delays=0.01/0/0.24/0.39, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <20160802215901.9B4C79DEDB@myawesomedomain.com> Queued mail for d$
Aug  2 21:59:02 myawesomedomain postfix/qmgr[27728]: 9B4C79DEDB: removed
Aug  2 21:59:02 myawesomedomain postfix/smtp[28282]: A1E649DEE8: to=<companyemailhostedatgmail@mycompanydomain.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.207.27]:25, delay=0.89, delays=0/0/0.49/0.39, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1470175142 s37si2836049qta.36 - gsmtp)
Aug  2 21:59:02 myawesomedomain postfix/qmgr[27728]: A1E649DEE8: removed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They **are** getting there.

```
(250 2.0.0 OK 1470175142 s37si2836049qta.36 - gsmtp)
```

That "250" is the SMTP 250 code, sent back to your server by Gmail, and it indicates that they accepted the email. Your hotmail attempt also shows a successful 250 code. If the email is not showing up in users' inboxes, it's likely getting identified as spam, and you'll need to put some working into making sure that your mails are not [being identified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam).

Comment: Thank you! At first my IP was blocked by the providers for abuse - it's a new linode instance, so whoever had the IP before me may have been a spammer. I had already sent a bunch of test emails from the same address and IP, so I guess I hit the spam filter too.

I found them in the spam folder - listed as being sent DAYS after they actually were sent, and unflagged one, and now they're getting where they should be going. I'm lucky they're admin emails, and only have to go to a fixed number of addresses, I'll make sure the users know that they could end up in spam.