# Sending mail when relay = 127.0.0.1 gives me 550-5.7.1 (gmail)

Tags: postfix, spam, gmail, email-bounces

When sending email using web UI (for example roundcube) and my relay is =127.0.0.1
I'm getting  this error

> host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.27] said: 550-5.7.1
>   [193.198.1.11      12] Our system has detected that this message is
>   550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent
>   to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
>   550-5.7.1

Excerpt from the /var/log/mail.log

```
Sep 14 21:28:06 mail postfix/qmgr[2915]: BB7418551: from=<xxxx@gkri.hr>, size=1082, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail amavis[2978]: (02978-01) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [193.198.1.11]:43798 [193.198.1.11] <xxxxxx@gkri.hr> -> <yyyyyyy@gmail.com>, Queue-ID: C953F422, Message-ID: <03227ea1376656afb567873be8981a60@gkri.hr>, mail_id: 15_o4VKBS9UP, Hits: -7.293, size: 700, queued_as: BB7418551, 3127 ms
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail postfix/smtp[3045]: C953F422: to=<yyyyyy@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=3.4, delays=0.17/0.05/0.04/3.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as BB7418551)
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail postfix/qmgr[2915]: C953F422: removed
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail postfix/smtpd[3021]: disconnect from mail.gkri.hr[193.198.1.11]
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail dovecot: imap(xxxxx@gkri.hr): Disconnected: Logged out in=605 out=520
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail postfix/smtpd[3004]: rewrite stream disconnect
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail postfix/smtp[3052]: BB7418551: to=<yyyyyy@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.27]:25, delay=0.73, delays=0.19/0.06/0.34/0.15, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [193.198.1.11      12] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError 550 5.7.1  for more information. qe3si5844139wjc.196 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail postfix/cleanup[3043]: 954E88552: message-id=<xxxxx@mail.gkri.hr>
Sep 14 21:28:07 mail postfix/bounce[3053]: BB7418551: sender non-delivery notification: 954E88552
```

When sending from a e-mail client application (Android) I'm able to send 
my status is sent and no error is visible (e-mail goes right through)

> status=sent 250 2.0.0 OK

```
Sep 14 21:37:04 mail postfix/qmgr[2915]: BE59C8551: from=<xxxxxxx@gkri.hr>, size=1893, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 14 21:37:04 mail postfix/smtpd[3179]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 14 21:37:04 mail amavis[2978]: (02978-04) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [89.172.131.36]:56139 [89.172.131.36] <xxxxxx@gkri.hr> -> <yyyyyyy@gmail.com>, Queue-ID: 0C126422, mail_id: 0O_1VMAZ9_sa, Hits: -3.523, size: 1511, queued_as: BE59C8551, 1501 ms
Sep 14 21:37:04 mail postfix/smtp[3177]: 0C126422: to=<yyyyyy@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.9, delays=0.36/0.04/0.01/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as BE59C8551)
Sep 14 21:37:04 mail postfix/qmgr[2915]: 0C126422: removed
Sep 14 21:37:05 mail postfix/smtp[3180]: BE59C8551: to=<yyyyyyy@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.71.26]:25, delay=0.62, delays=0.08/0.05/0.33/0.16, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1473881825 tv2si5887390wjb.173 - gsmtp)
```

I have reverse DNS (ptr) set up as well as SPF.

Headers of the rejected mail

```
eporting-MTA: dns; mail.gkri.hr
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 92014114E0
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; rene.brakus@gkri.hr
Arrival-Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:31:29 +0200 (CEST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; rene.brakus@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;rene.brakus@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [193.198.1.11      12] Our system has detected
    that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the
    amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked.
    Please visit 550-5.7.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError 550 5.7.1  for
    more information. d5si660227wjm.249 - gsmtp

Return-Path: <rene.brakus@gkri.hr>
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.gkri.hr (Postfix) with ESMTP id 92014114E0
    for <rene.brakus@gmail.com>; Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:31:29 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from mail.gkri.hr ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (mail.gkri.hr [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id hFJ_WfGPDrby for <rene.brakus@gmail.com>;
    Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:31:28 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from mail.gkri.hr (mail.gkri.hr [193.198.1.11])
    by mail.gkri.hr (Postfix) with ESMTPA id DEF0F114AA
    for <rene.brakus@gmail.com>; Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:31:27 +0200 (CEST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:31:27 +0200
From: Rene Brakus <rene.brakus@gkri.hr>
To: <rene.brakus@gmail.com>
Subject: 87687686
Organization: =?UTF-8?Q?Gradska_knji=C5=BEnica_Rijeka?=
Message-ID: <63143a0aefe8e00c9d080433cfe50492@gkri.hr>
X-Sender: rene.brakus@gkri.hr
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.9-svn
```

Headers of the e-mail that went through

```
Delivered-To: rene.brakus@gmail.com
Received: by 10.25.155.130 with SMTP id d124csp2856951lfe;
        Thu, 15 Sep 2016 01:09:06 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.194.139.236 with SMTP id rb12mr6579607wjb.101.1473926946908;
        Thu, 15 Sep 2016 01:09:06 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <rene.brakus@gkri.hr>
Received: from mail.gkri.hr (mail.gkri.hr. [193.198.1.11])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id t124si1544078wmt.5.2016.09.15.01.09.06
        for <rene.brakus@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 15 Sep 2016 01:09:06 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of rene.brakus@gkri.hr designates 193.198.1.11 as permitted sender) client-ip=193.198.1.11;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of rene.brakus@gkri.hr designates 193.198.1.11 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=rene.brakus@gkri.hr
Message-Id: <57da5722.822d1c0a.c3e70.4b27SMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com>
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mail.gkri.hr (Postfix) with ESMTP id 63D741148C for <rene.brakus@gmail.com>; Thu, 15 Sep 2016 10:09:07 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from mail.gkri.hr ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.gkri.hr [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id nTE8xSdhwfaS for <rene.brakus@gmail.com>; Thu, 15 Sep 2016 10:09:07 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from [192.168.88.209] (unknown [193.198.1.29]) by mail.gkri.hr (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 646EA11496 for <rene.brakus@gmail.com>; Thu, 15 Sep 2016 10:06:07 +0200 (CEST)
To: Rene <rene.brakus@gmail.com>
From: "rene.brakus@gkri.hr" <rene.brakus@gkri.hr>
Subject: Test
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 10:06:06 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_0_1473926766295"

------=_Part_0_1473926766295
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline

VGVzcgoK
------=_Part_0_1473926766295
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline

PGRpdiBzdHlsZT0iZm9udC1mYW1pbHk6ICdDYWxpYnJpJywgJ3NhbnMtc2VyaWYnOyI+PGRpdiBk
aXI9Imx0ciI+VGVzcjwvZGl2PjwvZGl2Pjxicj4=
------=_Part_0_1473926766295--
```

Comment: Your rejection error has a URL for more information.  I'd start there.

Comment: yes it has information about unsolicited e-mails, we've had issues with spam injections but have resolved it 10 days ago, and we are not on any black lists for over 8 days. We weren't able to send e-mail to gmail using any client or UI, but in the last 12 hours we are able to send only using client apps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Comment: I wouldn't begin to guess, without seeing full headers and body of the rejected message.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've added it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google's SMTP error reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en)

> 550, "5.7.1", Our system has detected that this message is likely
>   unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this
>   message has been blocked

Having this message in smtp log  lead me to believe that I am on some sort of a blacklist from google. 
But after configuring mail and DNS server and setting up SPF, DKIM and reverse DNS (PTR), gmails smtp is no longer bouncing my e-mails.

The thing that confused me the most is why one e-mail account from the server was able to send to gmail. I later on concluded that this was because of me giving this e-mail when ask to be removed from the black list using this [form](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/msgdelivery)

I hope my experience will help someone else too.