# Could two emails sent at the exact same time to the same user cause spam filtering?

Tags: email, email-server, spam, spam-filter

we are setting up a mail service which will send emails periodically.

There are two kinds of email.

One which is sent three times a day (8, 13, 17 o'clock). 
Another which MAY be sent at 8am depending on some criterion)
So there is the potential for 2 emails to be send at 8am.

I am worried about a user receiving two emails from the same address at the exact same time being marked potentially as spam by the email provider (I'm not concerned about the user marking it as spam - they asked for these emails).

Since we will be using our company mail server, if it gets blacklisted by IP or email address we could be in a lot of trouble.

If anyone could shed some light on this that would be great - I couldn't find anything at all on the topic online. My question is quite simply, How likely is it that we have any kind of trouble doing this? (Spam going to their spam box or worse trouble, getting blacklisted)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any valid reason _why_ the mails should be marked as spam (other than time)? Don't you think there are many mails floating around which are delivered at the same time?

Comment: From the same address no, I couldn't think of anything. Can you?

Comment: No...not at all

Comment: I just checked my own personal mail and even spam from Amazon has an hour delay or so. A few other newsletters I received on the same day were also staggered.

Comment: Wait. What is your question? That if your mails are sent at exactly the same time they'll be regarded as spam, or that _if_ they're regarded as spam that they'll be delivered too late?

Comment: "How likely is it that we have any kind of trouble doing this?" I'm talking about spam. If you have dealt with this situation before and had no problems then let me know :)

Comment: Not likely at all...why don't you just try it yourself manually?

Comment: As I said, if this gets us into trouble it will be big trouble. So asking the community first is a wise decision. Thanks for your input but do you have experience trying this?

Comment: Our monitoring sends dozens of mails at exactly the same time if something big happens, to external users as well. Never had any problems and couldn't even think of it creating one, other than faulty spamfilters.

Comment: OK but does it send dozens to the same person at the same time from the same server? You seem to be dodging a specific point with every reply

Comment: I'm not dodging anything, just trying to help? Again: _I_ can't think of any problem, if that doesn't suit you, alright. No idea what you're getting at. Anyway, I'm out...test it yourself, talk to your mail-server admin, to your ISP, whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?](http://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Comment: This is impossible to answer; email providers revise and alter their spam recognition systems all the time. There is no guarantee, ever, that any given email will be delivered.

Comment: So by that definition the answer is, Yes it could. Right?