# "My domain" is being recognized as spammer for "no reason"

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, spam

I linked my brand new domain, to `yandex.connect`and I sent only a few test emails, but NO email was sent or received.
I checked many times the DNSs and they seem to be fine,

When I send emails from any domain to `the domain` accounts, I get this alert:

`"The mail server responded:
550 5.7.1 Policy rejection on the target address."`

When I send emails from `the domain` to any domain (including itself), I get this alert:

`"The mail server responded:  5.7.1 [1]
Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM;"`

***What can the problem be?***

**UPDATE 1**

**1.-**  SPF, DKIM, DMARC and CNAME were configured from the very beginning but it didn't make a difference.

**2.-**  All IP's involved are clean on blacklists.

**UPDATE 2**

**Now I know the problem was related to SMTP BANNER, this causes Yandex security to recognize me as spammer. I still don't know the fix but that would close this thread. Thanks for your answers. If I find the fix I'll post a link.**

Comment: In general: https://serverfault.com/q/419407/37681

Comment: @HBruijn , I'm not receiving spam, but I'm the suspect of generating it.The domain, hosting(shared) and yandex account are brand new, bought/created a couple of days ago, and accessed only to configure it.

Comment: What is the IP address of your mail server? Policy rejections are often due to IP being "labeled" dynamic, but you need to give some information if you want any help here with it.

Comment: The page I linked contains also the things you need to do as the domain owner to not look like a spammer, I.e.  configure SPF, DKIM and DMARC - and on shared hosting possibly the “(bad) reputation” of the provider might be more decisive in recipients classifying your mail as spam than anything particular for your domain.

Comment: @HBruijn       I'll pay more attention then, thanks. Maybe I'll find something useful for my problem. :)

Comment: Also: https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam

Answer (score 2):

What server IP address are you sending your mail from?

If you're sending it from 198.57.234.7 - lots of places will reject your email because the PTR record doesn't match (host 198.57.234.7
7.234.57.198.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ope.open-comet.com.)

Comment: I think the problem is actually related to that. The NS is on buy.ooo, the hosting on epizy.com and the mail on yandex.net. 
I just found out the trouble could be an `SMTP BANNER` thing (I don't know what that is.)

Could you give me an idea on how to fix the PTR on a shared hosting, please?

Comment: I just found this page on that problem, but I can't really understand it:

https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/SMTP-Banner-Check?page=health_smtp&hidetoc=0&hidepitch=0&showlogin=1&action=smtp:mx.yandex.net&domain=numano.ooo

Comment: Strongly doubt it's that - The SMTP banner is what your server issues when a sending SMTP server connects to your server. The MX for numano.ooo is mx.yandex.net. When I connect to mx.yandex.net and try to send to test@numano.ooo it says 'unknown user' - so to be more specific I'd need to test a valid user.

Comment: you could use test@numano.ooo now. Could you share how you test it, please?

Comment: Now it's giving a different message:   
Trying 2a02:6b8::89...
Connected to mx.yandex.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mxfront4j.mail.yandex.net (Want to use Yandex.Mail for your domain? Visit http://pdd.yandex.ru)
HELO calvin.calvin
250 mxfront4j.mail.yandex.net
MAIL FROM:<test@example.com>
250 2.1.0 <test@example.com> ok
RCPT TO:<test@numano.ooo>
250 2.1.5 <test@numano.ooo> recipient ok
DATA
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
mail message here

.
552 5.2.2 Mailbox size limit exceeded 1537972086-ORGOZfCma8-RfwG8s29`

Comment: Now it's giving a different message:  
'telnet mx.yandex.net 25
    Trying 2a02:6b8::89...
    Connected to mx.yandex.net.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    220 mxfront4j.mail.yandex.net (Want to use Yandex.Mail for your domain?)
    HELO calvin.calvin
    250 mxfront4j.mail.yandex.net
    MAIL FROM:<test@example.com>
    250 2.1.0 <test@example.com> ok
    RCPT TO:<test@numano.ooo>
    250 2.1.5 <test@numano.ooo> recipient ok
    DATA
    354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
    mail message here
    .
    552 5.2.2 Mailbox size limit exceeded`

Comment: ok - can't get the formatting on this system right - but the last bit of my comment  above applies - read https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2010/02/17/manually-testing-smtp-mail-issues-via-telnet

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mail-Tester](https://www.mail-tester.com) free service to check your real test email sent to their server for all types of possible problems.

P.S. Your numano.ooo DNS don't have any DMARC records right now. It should not be the reason of rejecting all your mails as spam, but you are recommended to setup DMARC correctly.

Comment: It didn't help, since I needed to send an email to that domain from the problematic domain, which couldn't send or receive any mail. But thanks for the idea.