# Microsoft block email for no apparent reason

Tags: email, email-server, microsoft-office-365

I manage a couple of servers and 3 of them got flagged the same week by Microsoft and block all email these servers send and we get these errors :

> 550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] weren't sent.
>   Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their
>   network is on our block list (S3140). You can also refer your provider
>   to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.

2 of these server are dedicated servers (with WHM) that host around 70-90 clients and the other server is a VPS (with Plesk) for a single client.

On the servers with WHM, I checked the Mail Delivery Reports and I don't see sign of spam. Our abuse@ accounts only got 4 complaints last month.

I checked the reputation of the servers on talosintelligence.com and all servers got a "Good" email reputation.

I made a blacklist check on mxtoolbox.com and they are not listed on any list.

We contacted Microsoft multiple time and they always return us saying that the "IP do not qualify for mitigation at this time" and that they cannot give us more information.

We made multipe tests on glockapps.com, the test email got received without problem with every mail service expect for the ones from Microsoft. For Outlook, live, hotmail the message are never delivered and for Office365, it get spammed.

We have multiple client that call daily to know what is happening and frankly, I just don't know. Everything seems fine and Microsoft doesn't seem to want to help us.

Thank you

EDIT: Got contacted by OVH, Microsoft blocked a bunch of their IPs, so it was not on our side.

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/48428

Comment: This is not a question about Control Panel, I only added that detail to give the more info I could. The main question is that Microsoft think that our servers are suspect and I don't know why. Thanks

Comment: It involves panels and is OT because of that. Without the panel, I would have closed the question as duplicate of the one I linked above. That said: MS and Google have their own secret rules on what they block and unless you aren’t a big player yourself, you can’t do anything about it because they just don’t give a damn. And everyone using GMail, Google Apps, Office365 and similar services gives them more power to trample on the small players.

Comment: `Microsoft block email for no apparent reason` - `550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list (S3140).` - I'd say the reason is painfully, obviously, and undoubtedly apparent. Did you even read the message?

Comment: Saw your edit. If you would have read the actual message you wouldn't have wasted a bunch of time doing unnecessary troubleshooting. `Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list` - I mean, it doesn't get any clearer than that.

Comment: Passive aggressive comment aside, I read the message, I contacted OVH for information but was not getting an answer. I was not just gonna sit there while a bunch of client call to give us shit. I never saw something like that happen, so I tried everything I knew.