# AWS SES emails going to spam

Tags: php, email, curl, amazon-ses

I have a domain on name.com and the website is hosted on AWS Lightsail. I have set up SES service for the emails. I am doing a curl request to my domain to send an email from the email server which is also hosted on the same lightsail instance.

I have added all the DMARC records, DKIM records and SPF records. mail-tester shows 10/10 score. mxtoolbox also not showing any issues but still the emails are going to spam. The Test email from SES is also going to spam folder.

I am not getting what is the issue here. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your reverse DNS setting for all IP Addresses that you send email from.
You should set reverse DNS for the originating IP's so when you check your senders IP address in the following website, it returns the domain name of your SES:

https://www.whatismyip.com/reverse-dns-lookup/

https://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx