# Server and Application architecture for large outgoing email volume

Tags: smtp, spam, high-volume

we need to develop an application to send large amount of emails (newsletters)
We estimate 15 millions of emails per month (6 - 10 emails per seconds).

Would you recommend me the proper architecture for this application?
should we have several MTA agents and use them in a round robin fashion?
What considerations should we take on account to not being treated as spammers 
(its really not spam what we are going to send).

Thanks for your help.

Ezequiel

Comment: Ah - ok, so where is the large outgoing volume here? 6-10 emails per second was not impressive 10 years ago, it is definitely not impressive now. One server can handle that ;)

Comment: Agree with TomTom, if it was 6k-10k/sec it might need some thought, an iPhone could do 6-10/sec.

Comment: yes, you are right, the volume is not the major problem,
 but what about being considered spammer?

Comment: see this question http://serverfault.com/questions/41693/best-practices-for-preventing-you-from-looking-like-a-spammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a mailing list software like [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com) to

   - Not send emails to people who did not ask for it.
   - Include a Unsubscribe link in the Emails.
   - Stop sending emails to people who click on the link to unsubscribe.
   - If any emails bounce, remove that from the list.
2. To make sure your MTA is not considered a SPAMMer, take this [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test) from each of your MTA's and implement suggested fixes.
3. 6-10 emails per second is not a big deal. You should be able to put a reasonably powerful server (4GB RAM, some HDD, etc.) with Postfix and a good Internet line and achieve the speeds.
4. Once you start sending emails, participate in the Feedback Loop program of major Email providers.