# SMTP server problem

Tags: smtp

Our requirement is to send weekly newsletters to our website customers. For which we wanted to have local hosted SMTP server in our office. We are not using SMTP server provided by website hosting provider, as we wanted to reduce the network traffic and avoid IP blocking due to bulk mails.

We are sending newsletters on weekly basis from our local SMTP server. But due to some reasons, some emails are going to spam and some are not reaching to customers and sometimes there are bounce messages to follow bulk email guidelines (mainly from Gmail).

Can you please suggest me, how to achieve my problem. I also wanted to know what type of technology generally Linkedin or banks uses to send notifications emails to all its customers. When they send bulk emails, they will always reach inbox with out any problem.

I want the same solution to implement for my website. Please suggest me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a third-party company like [constant contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp).  If you really want to do this yourself, [look at this previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/41693/best-practices-for-preventing-you-from-looking-like-a-spammer) about not looking like spam.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much a question of a special solution, but you have to configure your mail server really tight and good to avoid getting marked as spammer.

The most important issues are:

- The server you want to use has to be listed with an MX record in the DNS for your domain
- It needs a valid reverse DNS (PTR) entry

  Both of this likely needs the cooperation of your provider
- It must not be an open relay.
- Having valid and good SPF and DKIM entries will help as well.

And the most important thing: Don't send spam, but only legitimate newsletter to persons who actively subscribed. If they unsubscribe, don't send them anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SvenW advice, several black-lists will include the IP address ranges of DSL-style connections, so your office IP address is probably included, even if you are a good netizen. You can use [services like this one](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/) to check your IP address.