# How to avoid outgoing emails to be flagged as spam by google?

Tags: ubuntu, email, spam, exim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Practices for preventing you from looking like a spammer](https://serverfault.com/questions/41693/best-practices-for-preventing-you-from-looking-like-a-spammer)

I use Exim4 as MTA on Ubuntu server. The problem is that all outgoing emails are being flagged as spam by google mail. It is very annoying. I appreciate your hints and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to look at is there being a valid reverse name for your mail server.  If your mail server is "mail.mycompany.com" yet when resolved, has a different name, some servers, like mine, will reject your email.  Another thing to verify is your mail server having an [SPF record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).  Little more information may help resolve this.

Comment: I addes SPF record to my DNS records, but it had not effect. HOw can I check the reverse name of the mail server?

Comment: Using mxtoolbox.com, I figured out that my IP has been blocked by two spam blacklists.

Answer (score 0):

there are too many factors. Your server have been send email out too many people and someone probably report your email as a spam email. I would rename the send email to something and send the email on the different email server with a different ip address.

Comment: Well, at least this is not the case. In fact this occured on a fresh install of the server.