# Emails safely reaching spam bin

Tags: spam

I started an emailing server. My emails are directly sent to Gmail, Yahoo, AOL & HotMail's spam bin. I can't understand how to fix my errors. I tried sending email to Hotmail which was marked as spam. I am posting the headers here and DNS records, anybody please find why my emails are marked as spam.

I have all records (DKIM, SPF) but in Hotmail headers all those are failed. I asked many people they said my records are correct. But my Hotmail is not detecing my records?

```
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=temperror(sender IP is 65.75.241.26) header.from=gimp@softmail.me; dkim=none header.d=softmail.me; x-hmca=none 
X-Message-Status: n:0:n
X-SID-PRA: gimp@softmail.me
X-DKIM-Result: None
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtTQ0w9NA==
X-Message-Info: 6sSXyD95QpXMBBxHETcC1TRV4SsboD8kDakWHqQ9t6wrQh0fwmer8aUvqtu7Nx1RPHsQsrhLyeB8/QSu8rpmokio6edoWdTLCCC9kJWBTFAjBVurlsVY+p/ylYRJi1G/
Received: from softmail.me ([65.75.241.26]) by SNT0-MC3-F34.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
     Sun, 4 Sep 2011 00:58:17 -0700
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]) by softmail.me with MailEnable ESMTP; Sun, 04 Sep 2011 04:01:29 -0400
Received: from 101.212.187.148 ([101.212.187.148]) by webmail.softmail.me
    (Horde MIME library) with HTTP; Sun, 04 Sep 2011 04:01:29 -0400
Message-ID: <20110904040129.2k6ya9140k8cw44o@webmail.softmail.me>
Date: Sun, 04 Sep 2011 04:01:29 -0400
From: gimp@softmail.me
To: karthikmalla@hotmail.com
Subject: hello
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=ISO-8859-1;
    DelSp="Yes";
    format="flowed"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
User-Agent: Internet Messaging Program (IMP) H3 (4.1.6)
Return-Path: gimp@softmail.me
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Sep 2011 07:58:17.0614 (UTC) FILETIME=[67EFA2E0:01CC6AD8]

test message.

----------------------------------------------------------------
This message was sent using IMP, the Internet Messaging Program.
```

My DNS records.

```
; SOA Record
SOFTMAIL.ME.    3600    IN  SOA ns35.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net (
                2011090100
                28800
                7200
                604800
                86400
                )

; A Records
@   3600    IN  A   65.75.241.26
beta    3600    IN  A   65.75.241.26
accs    3600    IN  A   65.75.241.26
test    3600    IN  A   65.75.241.26
mail    3600    IN  A   65.75.241.26
smtp    3600    IN  A   65.75.241.26
webmail 3600    IN  A   65.75.241.26

; CNAME Records
www 3600    IN  CNAME   @

; MX Records
@   3600    IN  MX  10  mail.softmail.me
@   3600    IN  MX  0   smtp.softmail.me

; TXT Records
@   3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr mx:mail.softmail.me include:softmail.me include:secureserver.net -all"
beta    3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr mx:smtp.softmail.me include:softmail.me include:secureserver.net -all"
@   3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr mx:smtp.softmail.me include:softmail.me include:secureserver.net -all"
key1._domainkey 3600    IN  TXT "k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCgaiG57vsLV8fiIC274NsoDx66O86+rWPBx5aDX6n+1oAKleZhTTV+cZ8eHhroknkgMu3p7njDxTkIqud5ExHlf8m5ymBiJ2seCh/vGy4gMp5g90HVdiTJlHjF7fH5oJzgJ7EsEZf7sPjfHWeDlydXQnpHZtpT5QsmMYAPJWp8XQIDAQAB"
_domainkey  3600    IN  TXT "t=y; o=~;"
july2011._domainkey 3600    IN  TXT "v=DKIM1; p=; s=email; t=s:y"

; NS Records
@   3600    IN  NS  ns35.domaincontrol.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns36.domaincontrol.com
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices for preventing you from looking like a spammer](http://serverfault.com/questions/41693/best-practices-for-preventing-you-from-looking-like-a-spammer)

Comment: @mailq - I believe that my question is completely different. I have all records (DKIM, SPF) but in Hotmail headers all those are failed. I asked many people they said my records are correct. But my Hotmail is not detecing my records?

Answer (score 6):

You have two TXT records for SPF. That's bad and wrong. Check your entries via http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

Then you include the SPF record recursively with `include:softmail.me`. That's evil, too.

Nonetheless you do not sign your message with DKIM and then you wonder yourself why the signature can't be verified?!

So all the "many people" you asked are wrong. Ask the real people who know about SPF and DKIM and read the documentation about it.

Comment: Which SPF record should I delete in the following `v=spf1 a mx ptr mx:smtp.softmail.me include:softmail.me include:secureserver.net -all` or `v=spf1 a mx ptr mx:mail.softmail.me include:softmail.me include:secureserver.net -all`

Comment: The one you don't need. It's you who carefully thought about the content, right? So I can't recommend your setup. Just delete one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SPF records, so the above poster could have the answer...

However, how long has this issue been happening? If it just started today, then Godaddy may be the problem. I read that they have been banning high usage hosts from their DNS servers without a lot more information. If hotmail.com and the other big email servers have "Accidently" been denied access to the DNS server by godaddy, your email is likely to end up in the spam box. Just something to consider.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I already tried using different DNS before. I am encountering this issue from past 6 months.

Comment: Headers are very clear that my records are not passed. Seems there are some syntax errors in DNS records.

Comment: All good, just thought it *could* be relevant if the issue just started to happen.